# How to integrate plugin “Kiosk” in Ionic 3 app?

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I want to disable the back, the home, the right button and if it is possible the button which closes the device.
Someone in here recommend this plugin for me.
Cordova has a Kiosk mode plugin: [https://github.com/hkalina/cordova-plugin-kiosk](https://github.com/hkalina/cordova-plugin-kiosk.).

My problem is that I can't make it work.
I tried to put:

```
1) window["Kiosk"].isInKiosk((isInKiosk)=>{ this.imer = isInKiosk; }).catch(error=>this.imer = 'no');

2) cordova.plugins.Kiosk.isInKiosk((isInKiosk)=>{ this.imer = isInKiosk; });

3) declare let Kiosk:any
   and in constructor this:
   Kiosk.setKioskEnabled(true);
```

I think I do something wrong.

How to install this *(cordova plugin)* in **IONIC 3**, from the beginning?

Could you provide me all the details or guide me in order to make this work?

If it is not possible please suggest another method.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is the error that you have when calling the plugin method?

Comment: Failed to fetch plugin github.com/hkalina/cordova-plugin-kiosk.git via registry.

Comment: But, this is installation error, rather than usage error. So, you couldn’t install the plugin yet?

Comment: No I think it is not possible. That plugin is only for cordova apps. But someone told me that it worked for him. Even the creator didn't reply for this question yet. Did you use that plugin?

Comment: is your ionic app running on capacitor or cordova?

Comment: Ionic 3 with cordova